# What is the corresponding LINQ Statement for the following sql statement

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

**I have two table:**

```
tblCategory (ID, CategoryName, ParentCategoryID)

tblFile (ID, Name, CategoryID, USerID, LanguageID, UpadateDateTime, 
         ActiveDateTime, FilePath)
```

I want to retrieved all data from tblFile table where the tblCategory.ParentCategoryID = 1 of the CategoryID of the tblFile table. I want to do something like below:

```
Select * from tblFile where CategoryID is in 
(select ID from tblCategory where ParentCategoryID =1) && 
UploadDateTime >= startDate && UploadDateTime <= endDate
```

Here, I want to retrieve all data which belongs to particular parent category e.g. 1 in the tblCategory. CategoryID is foreign key of tblFile corresponds to ID of tblCategory.

And, What is LINQ Statement or Entity Framework for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = _db.tblFile.Where(x=> x.UploadDateTime >= startDate && UploadDateTime <= endDate && (_db.tblCategory.Where(c=> c.ParentCategoryId == 1).Select(c=> c.Id).ToArray().Contains(x.CategoryID)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the FK relationship between `tblCategories` and `tblFiles` exists in your EF model and has the default naming, you can use the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) projection with filters on both tables:

```
db.tblCategories.Where(cat => cat.ParentCategoryID == 1)
             .SelectMany(cat => cat.tblFiles)
             .Where(file => file.UploadDateTime >= startDate && file.UploadDateTime <= endDate)
```

**Update**

I believe that your SQL can be simplified with a join:

```
Select * 
  from tblFile f join tblCategory cat
       on f.CategoryID = cat.ID
  where cat.ParentCategoryID =1
        and f.UploadDateTime >= @startDate && f.UploadDateTime <= @endDate
```